# Docker create container without internet access on MacOSX with Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, macos, networking, docker-desktop

I'd like to create a container via the docker rest api which will be accessible from the host but without external network access.

I've read the docs a couple times but still not able to get it to work.

When passing in the network name as the network to connect to when starting, there are no ports exposed.

If I connect at a later time, the container is connected to 2 networks - the default bridge, and my network. The exposed ports are working correctly in the latter case.

How do I configure this?

EDIT:

I did some more experiments - I was setting

```
Internal: true
```

Which according to the docs makes it so that only other containers connected will have access to the container.

I'd like to access the container from the host so the network cannot be internal.

Setting it to False allows me to access the container, but I can also connect to google from within the container.

Relevant reading:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate

[https://threatpicture.com/blog/restrict-internet-access-docker-container/#:~:text=Another%20way%20to%20prevent%20a,the%20host%20and%20the%20internet](https://threatpicture.com/blog/restrict-internet-access-docker-container/#:%7E:text=Another%20way%20to%20prevent%20a,the%20host%20and%20the%20internet).

The second link talks about creating a bridge network which by default shouldn't have an external gateway.

Here is the network inspected as well as some other useful info

```
=> docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                   NAMES
cecb660da65c   datumai/mh-mock-runtime:latest   "uvicorn app.main:ap…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:55807->80/tcp   datumai-model

=> docker inspect ID_CONTAINER

 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "f5509cdf337b740ad50290766854aebddadd802366c780cf4d5e31a7050ffbd7",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "55807"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f5509cdf337b",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "datumai-model-network-offline": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "cecb660da65c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "59d034f30a97de377c6d3745b1b5764c487d58a5aa2e69dedd2dc7f4ece71e33",
                    "EndpointID": "f12b9a39c85ecda7f60edea34c09cc8773eb61be90dee281228b59d7bb6eba47",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.27.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }

=> docker inspect ID_OF_NETWORK

[
    {
        "Name": "datumai-model-network-offline",
        "Id": "59d034f30a97de377c6d3745b1b5764c487d58a5aa2e69dedd2dc7f4ece71e33",
        "Created": "2024-01-07T02:48:35.182210136Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "e42176ec9ae1b540a3703ccd6c09d44782dd17e5fba8bc7d4ff2a7403daf729a": {
                "Name": "datumai-model",
                "EndpointID": "e9ec6900d53c772a84f136d2599b1410aca0366518009a522a31b78de70a00d0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.datumai.model": "true"
        }
    }
]
```

EDIT 2:

The answer below mentions that an internal network should work just fine. Unfortunately, it seems that for my setup - which is Docker Desktop on a MacOSX M2, it doesn't work that way.

Reproducing the issue:

```
docker network create --internal internal
docker run --net internal --rm --name web docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

in a new tab

```
=> docker container inspect web --format '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.internal.IPAddress}}'

172.29.0.2:8080
```

The call to curl from host:

```
=> curl 172.29.0.2:8080
hangs, then shows
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.29.0.2 port 8080 after 75009 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're doing here -- on the one hand, you want a container without internet access. On the other hand, it sounds like you're connecting both to the default bridge network and to another network. Please show us the REST API call you're making (or the equivalent `docker run` command).

Comment: @larsks updated the question with more info, I hope this clears it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to access the container from the host so the network cannot be internal.

In fact, you can access a container from the host even when using the `internal` network as long as you access the container ip directly (rather than using port publishing). For example, if we start up a simple web server like this:

```
docker network create --internal internal
docker run --net internal --rm --name web docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

We can get the container ip address like this:

```
$ docker container inspect web --format '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.internal.IPAddress}}'
192.168.224.2
```

And we can successfully connect to the web service in that container:

```
$ curl 192.168.224.2:8080
<html>
...
</html>
```

Because it's on an `internal` network, the container doesn't have outbound network connectivity:

```
$ docker exec -it web wget -O- google.com
wget: bad address 'google.com'
$ docker exec -it web wget -O- 142.251.40.206
Connecting to 142.251.40.206 (142.251.40.206:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (142.251.40.206): Operation timed out
```

> The second link talks about creating a bridge network which by default shouldn't have an external gateway.

That is highly inaccurate. A bridge network is the most common type of Docker network, and of course it has a default gateway because most folks *do* want outbound network access:

```
$ docker network create --driver=bridge mynetwork
52d2506adc651486300a95ea80855822180c2af0242ca1572ed6ab71e748de37
$ docker run --rm --net mynetwork docker.io/alpine ip route
default via 192.168.240.1 dev eth0
192.168.240.0/20 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.240.2
```

Comment: so unfortunately this is not the case - I'm suspecting a different behavior of how it's implemented on docker desktop, I'm on a MacOS M2.

I can see the IP - `172.29.0.2` but trying to curl from host results in a timeout.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that you are using docker desktop. You may want to update your question to indicate that, along with which platform you're using (Mac or Windows). I'm running Docker (just plain Docker, not Docker Desktop) on Linux, and the above works as described. The problem with Docker under Mac or Windows is that Docker is running inside a Linux virtual machine, so there's a level of indirection involved in network access that complicates things a bit.

Comment: I have update the question with more details, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get the behavior I want, but unfortunatelly that required a workaround by running an additional proxy. The approach isn't perfect but it might help someone down the line.

Here are the rough steps to follow

- Create an internal network as suggested
- Create another container with an nginx proxy. It should connect to the default bridge network. You also need to publish a single port of the proxy so your host can access the proxy.
- Connect that container to the internal network above.

I've used https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

The configuration requires the following:

- mount the docker socket when starting the proxy container
- add env variable called VIRTUAL_HOST, in my case I set it to datumai-model.local

The calls to the containers need to be routed through the proxy container, which needs the Host header set to the VIRTUAL_HOST above.

e.g.

```
curl -H "Host: <VIRTUAL_HOST>" http://localhost:<FORWARDED_PORT_OF_PROXY>
```

Finally a call to the service succeeds, but any queries inside the container to e.g. google fail.